# Java - Spring - Security not working due to transaction not detected

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, security, transactions

I am trying to build an simple CRM spring app with a security layer.

My use case is simple : login page which allows the access the customer list and also to add new user from it.

[image]

I have created a client config class for the customer management and a security config class.
The security config file defined it own data source, transactional manager and session factory to access a dedicated db which manage the users :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@PropertySource("classpath:security-persistence-mysql.properties")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Bean(name = "securitySessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(securityDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.luv2code.springdemo");

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "securityDataSource")
    public DataSource securityDataSource() {

        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        try {
            dataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.security.url"));
        logger.info("URL security config : " + env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));

        dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(
                getPropertyAsInt("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(
                getPropertyAsInt("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(
                getPropertyAsInt("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));
        dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(
                getPropertyAsInt("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    private int getPropertyAsInt(String key) {
        return Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty(key));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/customer/**").hasRole("EMPLOYE")
                .antMatchers("/leaders/**").hasRole("MANAGER")
                .antMatchers("/systems/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/createUser").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authentificateTheUser")
                .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler).permitAll()
                .and().logout().permitAll().and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {

        Properties hibernatePpt = new Properties();
        hibernatePpt.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        hibernatePpt.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        hibernatePpt.setProperty("hibernate.packagesToScan",
                env.getProperty("hibernate.packagesToScan"));

        return hibernatePpt;
    }

    @Bean(name = "securtiyTransactionManager")
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("securitySessionFactory")
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        // setup transaction manager based on session factory
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }

}
```

For the security and login I am not using the default user management but a custom one with a Role and User entity with a join table :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "username")
private String userName;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Collection<Role> roles;
//constructors, getter,setter

}
```

Role :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
```

//.....
}

I use a service and dao layer to access the user with hibernate.

My issue is that when I try to loggin or add a user I have an exception : Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

The thing is use the transactional annotation.
First I go through the controller :

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @GetMapping("/showMyLoginPage")
    public String showMyLoginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/access-denied")
    public String showAccesDenied() {

        return "access-denied";
    }
}
```

Then the jsp :

<form:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/authenticateTheUser">

User name :

Password :

</form:form>

```
    <form:form method="GET" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/createUser">
    <input type="submit" value="Registration">
    </form:form>
```

When the jsp is submitted it calls the user service details (Autowired in the config class) and the method loadUserByUsername which is under transaction :

```
public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService

@Service
@Transactional("securtiyTransactionManager")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDAO.getUser(userName);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                    "Invalid username or password.");
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(),
                mapRolesToAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
    }




    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthorities(
            Collection<Role> roles) {
        return roles.stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Somehow the transaction is not working but I don't know why.
I parallel I have my other config file which manage the customer use cases.

Thx for any help to understand what is wrong.

For information the full project is here : https://github.com/moutyque/CRM

Comment: I have looked at your code. I guess there is a small problem in @Qualifier of security securitySessionFactory in transaction bean definition.
Qualifier can be in method parameters to ensure sessionfactory is securitySessionFactory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @Bean(name = "securtiyTransactionManager")
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(
             @Qualifier("securitySessionFactory") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        // setup transaction manager based on session factory
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }
```

I can only guess your error with just looking at it. You can open log level for transactions to examine issue. Qualifier can be inline in method parameter to ensure securitySessionFactory is autowired.